# Django adding letters and numbers to imageField url

Tags: django-models, imagefield

I have an ImageField in a django model

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

My media root is set like so in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/art/'
```

But when I upload select a gif url for the Imagefield, the url does not save as /art/images

I get this error message in Django Admin when I upload the url for the gif "Barnie.gif", which is stored at `art/images/Barnie.gif`

```
Art with ID "1/change/images/Barnie_L2fAl.gif" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding the following imports:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

I also added the following `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try to get away with not doing all the config stuff, but you do have to do that.

In my base app urls.py I added:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

and at the end of the urls list I added:

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then in my settings.py I added:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/art/images')

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```